# Select object by value from enum

Tags: kotlin

I have an enum class. I need, depending on the value, to choose one of the services (in the `getMessage` function).

```
interface MyService<K, V> {
    fun message(): V
}

@Service
class FirstService : MyService<String, String> {
    override fun message(): String {
        return "It's first service"
    }
}

@Service
class SecondService : MyService<Long, Long> {
    override fun message(): Long {
        return 3
    }
}

enum class ServiceType {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}

@Service
class Handler(
    @Autowired val firstService: MyService<String, String>,
    @Autowired val secondService: MyService<Long, Long>
) {

    fun sayMessage() {
        println(getMessage(ServiceType.FIRST))
        println(getMessage(ServiceType.SECOND))
    }

    private fun getMessage(type: ServiceType) = when (type) {
        ServiceType.FIRST -> firstService
        ServiceType.SECOND -> secondService
    }.message()
}
```

Is there any way to rewrite this code without using `when` and `if`?

```
when (type) {
        ServiceType.FIRST -> firstService
        ServiceType.SECOND -> secondService
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to get rid of this " when " in your case because the services are injected and cannot be build inside the enum.

If the value that you want to get can be created or referenced inside the enum you could add an abstract service property inside it and override it in each enum (FIRST and SECOND) :

For exemple :

```kotlin
enum class ServiceType {
    FIRST {
        override val service: MyService<*, *> = FirstService()
    },
    SECOND {
        override val service: MyService<*, *> = SecondService()
    };

    abstract val service: MyService<*,*>
}
```

And you could use it like this :

```kotlin
    private fun getMessage(type: ServiceType) = type.service.message()
```

And again, in your specific case, you CANNOT use this approach.

In my point of view, it's the only way to get rid of a when or if.